# Iterate through excel sheet and merge rows depending on column values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large excel sheet I'm working with. Each row consists of five columns, as example below

```
 A    B    C            D               E
AAA | B | 350 | Param1=10;Param2=20; | CC |
AAA | B | 350 | Param1=20;Param2=30; | CC |
AAA | C | 350 | Param1=10;Param2=20; | DD |
AAA | B | 350 | Param1=40;Param2=70; | CC |
```

What I want to achieve is to merge rows where column A, B, C and E are equivalent. If these columns are equivalent then I want the rows to be deleted and the values of column D to be merged with a comma in between, i.e. I'd like the rows - after I've run the script - to be according to the following

```
 A    B    C            D                          E
AAA | B | 350 | Param1=10,20,40;Param2=20,30,70; | CC
AAA | C | 350 | Param1=10;Param2=20;             | DD
```

EDIT: Also, the values following each param in the D column must be unique. If there are several rows with Param2=20 then it should just say 20 one time.

I've never used VBA before. Is this achievable?

Comment: This is covered by Microsoft here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a collection. Loop through every line and make a key based on the value in columns A, B, C and E, f.i. "AAA-B-350-CC" for the first line. Add the parameters (column D) and the key to the collection.

```
pseudo code

dim col as new Collection
dim strKey as String
dim strValue as String

strKey = "AAA-B-350-CC" 'coming from the columns A, B, C, E
strValue = "AAA-B-350-CC@Param=..." 'coming from strKey and column D
```

Go to the next line. If the key does not exist, add the parameters to the collection with the key.
If the key does exist. Get the value from the collection, add the parameter values to it. Remove the parameter from the collection and add it again with the key (this is the only way to replace the value).

When all rows are processed, clear the sheet and loop through the collection. Split the value in key part (containing the original column values) and value part (parameters). Split the key part in values for the columns A, B, C and E and store the value part in E. You can use the split function for this.

```
strValue = "AAA-B-350-CC@Param=10;"
astrParts = split(strValue, "@");
'astrParts[0] contains the keypart
'astrParts[1] contains value part
astrColumns = split(astrParts[0], "-");
'astrColumns[0] contains value for kolom A
'astrColumns[1] contains value for kolom B
' etc.
```